# How to shutdown ActiveMQ session thread gracefully on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

How can we gracefully shutdown the daemon thread [ActiveMQ Session: ID:PC-63704-1472105244157-1:1:1]?

We have a spring-boot based web app which runs on `tomcat 8`. And using `Spring JMS 4.2.4.RELEASE` to send/receive message to/from `ActiveMQ 5.13.0`.

The activeMQ related libs are as below(All version are 5.13.0)

```
<properties>
    <activemq.version>5.13.0</activemq.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-jms-pool</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The spring-boot activeMQ settings are simply as follows

```
spring.activemq.mqtt.broker-url=tcp://127.0.0.1:1883
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://127.0.0.1:61616
spring.activemq.in-memory=false
spring.activemq.pooled=true
```

For sending message, we just simply autowired the JmsTemplate and send message out:

```
@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

MessageCreator messageCreator = new MessageCreator() {
    @Override
    public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
        // return Message
    }
};

jmsTemplate.send(new ActiveMQTopic(destinationName), messageCreator);
```

For receive(listening) message, we using Spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer(DMLC)

```
@Bean(name = { "afterCreateQueue" })
public Queue afterCreateQueue() {
    return new ActiveMQQueue(properties.getId() + "_After_Create_Queue");
}

@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer afterCreateJmsListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
        throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
    final DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    defaultMessageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    defaultMessageListenerContainer.setDestination(afterCreateQueue());

    final MessageListenerAdapter listener = new MessageListenerAdapter(afterCreateMessageDelegate());
    listener.setDefaultListenerMethod("handleMessage");

    defaultMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(listener);
    return defaultMessageListenerContainer;
}
```

When we shutdown tomcat, there will have warning log as below

```
22-Aug-2016 17:23:32.870 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [demo] appears to have started a thread named [ActiveMQ Session: ID:PC-63704-1472105244157-1:1:1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
org.apache.activemq.thread.DedicatedTaskRunner.runTask(DedicatedTaskRunner.java:119)
org.apache.activemq.thread.DedicatedTaskRunner$1.run(DedicatedTaskRunner.java:42)
22-Aug-2016 17:23:32.872 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [demo] appears to have started a thread named [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I close the application, the tomcat thread stack will have a daemon thread **[ActiveMQ Session: ID:PC-63704-1472105244157-1:1:1]** hanging there

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap at localhost:63675    
Thread [main] (Running) 
Daemon Thread [NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-1] (Running) 
Daemon Thread [NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-2] (Running) 
Daemon Thread [NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-3] (Running) 
Daemon Thread [AsyncLogger-1] (Running) 
Thread [ActiveMQ Session: ID:PC-63704-1472105244157-1:1:1] (Running)    
Daemon Thread [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] (Running)    
Daemon Thread [http-nio-1010-ClientPoller-0] (Running)  
Daemon Thread [http-nio-1010-ClientPoller-1] (Running)  
Daemon Thread [http-nio-1010-Acceptor-0] (Running)  
Daemon Thread [http-nio-1443-ClientPoller-0] (Running)  
Daemon Thread [http-nio-1443-ClientPoller-1] (Running)  
Daemon Thread [http-nio-1443-Acceptor-0] (Running)  
Daemon Thread [ajp-nio-8019-ClientPoller-0] (Running)   
Daemon Thread [ajp-nio-8019-ClientPoller-1] (Running)   
Daemon Thread [ajp-nio-8019-Acceptor-0] (Running)   
Daemon Thread [http-nio-1010-exec-1] (Running)
```

The stack of this **[ActiveMQ Session: ID:PC-63704-1472105244157-1:1:1]** thread as below

```
Thread [ActiveMQ Session: ID:MoboLink-63704-1472105244157-1:1:1] (Suspended)    
waiting for: Object  (id=96)    
Object.wait(long) line: not available [native method]   
Object.wait() line: 502 
DedicatedTaskRunner.runTask() line: 119 
DedicatedTaskRunner$1.run() line: 42
```

We have already handled the shutdown of `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` and also `PooledConnectionFactory` in `ContextClosedEvent` as below, but it still has the **[ActiveMQ Session: ID:PC-63704-1472105244157-1:1:1]** thread hanging there.

```
@Autowired
private DefaultMessageListenerContainer afterCreateJmsListenerContainer;
@Autowired
private PooledConnectionFactory pooledJmsConnectionFactory;

@EventListener
private void onContextClosed(ContextClosedEvent event)
{
    try
    {
        if (afterCreateJmsListenerContainer != null) {
            afterCreateJmsListenerContainer.shutdown();
        }

        if (pooledJmsConnectionFactory != null) {
            pooledJmsConnectionFactory.clear();
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Exception", e);
    }
}
```

Are there any other settings we have miss?

Answer (score 1):

See receiveTimeout setting in the DefaultMessageListenerContainer , if it is -1 the listener thread is blocked till it gets a message, otherwise every timeout period it will check if consumer is stopped.The default value is 1000ms.
[Source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java)

The setting will also stop that particular listener if no messages received in the period after specified retries, other settings could be used to control number of active listeners. See [here](http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/tuning-jms-message-consumption-in.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723864/gracefully-stop-defaultmessagelistenercontainer-having-a-receivetimeout-1).